# How can I convert a column of data into bytes in R?

Tags: r, binary, analysis

For analysis in R :

I have a column of data roughly 5000 numbers which are either a `1` or `0` -
for example : `11110110111111001010100001`

I would like this to be read in a **4 byte format** so that this I can identify patterns of the 64 possibilities:
E.g.

```
1111
0111
1011
1101
0110
```

Is there a way that I can convert this original column to these 4 sections and then identify the numbers of each of the sequences. I want to read to the left, and analyse the patterns. Was thinking that it would be a loop? I am using this data in R.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please, add more related tags. analysis is a general concept and it cannot help to lie your question in an appropriate community.

Answer (score 0):

With exmple data

```
  data <- sample(0:1,40,replace=T)
```

we can

```
split(data, ceiling(seq_along(data)/4))

$`1`
[1] 0 0 1 1

$`2`
[1] 1 0 1 0

$`3`
[1] 1 1 0 0

$`4`
[1] 0 1 0 1

$`5`
[1] 0 1 0 1

$`6`
[1] 1 1 1 1

$`7`
[1] 1 0 1 1

$`8`
[1] 1 0 0 1

$`9`
[1] 1 1 0 1

$`10`
[1] 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks, ive tried that but it gave an error. Will this just split the data? how can I read the data by one increment down?